# Как преобразовать объект в одномерный массив в JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Задача - преобразовать объект с вложенностью в одномерный массив

```
let arr = {caption: 'Miss1',
    commands: [
        {caption: 'Miss2'},
        {caption: 'Hit1', commands: [{caption: 'Miss3'}]}
    ]}
```

результат:

```
[['Miss1', 'Miss2'],
['Miss1', 'Hit1', 'Miss3']]
```

Comment: меня как бы смущает сама структура ответа.Не может быть такой

Comment: `{'Miss1', 'Miss2'}` - так не бывает. Либо массив `[value1, value2]`, либо объект `{ key: value }`

Comment: ой, устроит массив [value1, value2], исправляю в шапке

Comment: а для такого объекта какой должен быть результат: `{caption: 'Miss1',
    commands: [
        {caption: 'Miss2'},
        {caption: 'Hit1', commands: [{caption: 'Miss3'}, {caption: 'Miss4'}]}
    ]}`

Answer (score -1):

```js
let arr = {
  caption: 'Miss1',
  commands: [
    {
      caption: 'Miss2'
    },
    {
      caption: 'Hit1', 
      commands: [
        {
          caption: 'Miss3'
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
};

function getCaptionFromObj(arr, arrs = []){
    for (let key in arr) {
      let item = arr[key];
      if(key == "caption"){
         arrs.push(item);
      } else {
         getCaptionFromObj(item, arrs);
      }
    }
  return arrs;
}

console.log(getCaptionFromObj(arr));
```

Comment: Ответ не тот, который хочет автор

Comment: @Grundy согласно комментарию делал

Comment: Тот комментарий был ответом на вопрос про неверный формат и после него был обновлен вопрос: поменялись только фигурные скобки на квадратные.

Comment: @Grundy правильно, неверный формат ответа(результата), он и указал, что устроит `[value1, value2]`

Comment: Ага, **вместо** `{value1, value2}` так как это это ошибка синтаксиса, а не то, что нужно оставить плоский список.

Comment: @Grundy `Задача - преобразовать объект с вложенностью в одномерный массив`. На выходу у меня одномерный массив. Что не так то?

Comment: пример вывода добавлен в вопрос, у тебя результат не соответствует ожидаемому.

Comment: @Grundy в задаче у него одномерный массив, в результате он просит двумерный. При этом, если брать в пример его результат, то первый массив ещё понятно как получить, а вот со вторым уже начинают сложности,  откуда у него появилось значение из первого массива?. Поэтому я сделал, как описано в задаче, а не в желаемом результате.

Comment: И поэтому твой ответ неверный :-)